# jwplayer - black screen

Tags: jwplayer, akamai, jwplayer7

I get a black screen on loading a stream from akamai (manifest.f4m)
If I forward the video, the videoimage is showing correctly. Also, lets say, 1 from 10 times, the video is starting correctly, but mostly its coming up with a black screen (but playing)

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("video").setup({
                    primary: "flash",
                    width:"100%",
                    autostart: true,
                    playlist: [{
                        sources: [{
                            file: res.streamurl,
                            type:'mp4'
                        }],
                        provider: "/public/jwplayer/AkamaiAdvancedJWStreamProvider.swf"
                    }]
            });
```

Does anybody know what could cause this?

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image file, otherwise the player will default to a black screen before playing.

More info here: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#playlist